# More content in gcm notification meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am working with GCM notification in my Meteor app. The code goes as follows

```
    var gcm = Meteor.npmRequire('node-gcm');
var message = new gcm.Message({
    collapseKey:new Date().getTime().toString(),
    delayWhileIdle: false,
    timeToLive: 2419200,
    data: {
        "title": "some Title",
        "message":"some Message"
    }
});

message.addData('msgcnt','3');
message.addData("notId", parseInt(Math.random() * 25));
var sender = new gcm.Sender('XXXXX');
var registrationIds = [];
registrationIds.push('XXXX');
sender.send(message, registrationIds, 5, function (err, result) {
    if(err) {
    }
    else   {
        console.log(message);
    }
});
```

The above code gives me a notification with title in bold and beneath the title, I have single line of message. But I do not want the title, instead I want to accommodate more lines of messages in my notification.

Like when I get a notification, I should just see about few lines of messages with no headers. How should I do it in GCM?

Comment: This is handled client-side, so your question is not related to node.js or javascript. It is all down to how you display the data from the notification in your Android app.

Comment: Ok. Can u please guide me how that is to be done. I would be really grateful. Thanks.

Comment: You *might* be looking for something like this (but I am not sure from your question): https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html

Comment: I agree with Niels in that this is handled on the client-side. Your node server will only be able to send the info needed, like what text to display, but it is up to your Android app to place this text in a notification that will get displayed on the phone's screen.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement [Big View styles](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html), which help generate notifications with a lot of text. In particular, you will need to call `setStyle` on your notification builder as follows:

```
.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
            .bigText(msg))
```

This needs to be implemented in your client code, which is on Android.

Comment: But I really wonder how can I do that in meteor. As in Meteor, we have both client and server side code in Javascript. And I am using some meteor packages to send notification.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Unfortunately, client side JavaScript still runs on a web page. GCM is meant to send messages from a server to an Android client app. I assume this is what you intended, to reach an Android app. If not, check out GCM for Chrome extensions.

Comment: Just to add, I see that meteor has now added Phonegap support. Is that what you intend to use?

Comment: yes, I have already used that and I am successful in sending notification too. But my notifications contains a header and a single line message. Instead I want to remove the header and add more of messages.